# PHPmailer file attachement not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is my email send php file , email sent but attachment is not working. File is there on that path . Issue is I need to get file name from a linux command and store in a variable . When I called that variable attachment is not working.

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$file_name1 = shell_exec('sed "1q;d" /tmp/file.txt');
$file = "/home/user/.$file_name1";
echo $file;


//set Address data
$mail->Subject = "Acknowledgement Files ".date("m-d-Y:h:i:s")." ";
$mail->MsgHTML(" Acknowledgement Files are here attached");
$mail->AddAttachment($file)


if($mail->Send()) {
        echo "Message sent!";
} else {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

If I am going to use full path like

`$file = "/home/user/filetxt"`

this works but I want to call variable and echo is display correct name.
any thoughts?

Comment: did you try realpath($path_of_file) ?

Comment: `$file = "/home/user/.$file_name1";`  is wrong either use `$file = "/home/user/$file_name1";` or `$file = "/home/user/".$file_name1;`

Comment: Check your file path and please see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: none of the mentioned comment is working

Answer (score 1):

Put your variable outside the quotation, like this:

```
    $file = "/home/user/".$file_name1;
```

Comment: I already tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

So I found issue and solution as well. So when we run any command on linux like`ls /path/` output is `result\n`. It adds new line charactor as well.  So I changed this line

`$file_name1 = shell_exec('sed "1q;d" /tmp/file.txt');`

to

**`$file_name1 = trim(shell_exec('sed "1q;d" /tmp/file.txt'));`**

to remove new line . AND now it works